# In Android 12 DocumentFile toString() doesn't return text contrarely to previous versions

Tags: android, android-12

If I have a text file and i read it using `DocumentFile` when I call `myDocumentFile.toString()` I get its textual content as `String`.
In Android 12 if I call `myDocumentFile.toString()` on a text file loaded as `DocumentFile` rather than textual content I get as `String` something like

```
androidx.documentfile.provider.TreeDocumentFile@81660cb
```

It's not clear why this change of behaviour.

What is the most concise way to get its content as String?

Answer (score 0):

> If I have a text file and i read it using DocumentFile when I call myDocumentFile.toString() I get its textual content as String.

That is not the behavior of `DocumentFile`.

`DocumentFile` itself is an abstract class. [This is the source code to `1.0.1` of `DocumentFile`](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/documentfile/documentfile/1.0.1-source/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile.java.html), which right now is the most recent stable version. It has not changed since 2019. It has no `toString()` implementation.

Your question does not contain details of where and how you obtained the `DocumentFile`. Based on parts of your question, it appears that your object is an instance of `TreeDocumentFile`, a concrete subclass of `DocumentFile`. [This is the source code to `1.0.1` of `TreeDocumentFile`](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/documentfile/documentfile/1.0.1-source/androidx/documentfile/provider/TreeDocumentFile.java.html). It has not changed since 2019. It does not have a `toString()` implementation.

Since neither `DocumentFile` nor `TreeDocumentFile` have `toString()`, and `DocumentFile` only extends the base `Object` class, you inherit the `Object` implementation of `toString()`, which generates results like you show in your question (`androidx.documentfile.provider.TreeDocumentFile@81660cb`).

Note that neither of these are affected by Android OS version, because they come from [a library](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/documentfile/documentfile/1.0.1). Your implementation of `DocumentFile` is the same on Android 4.0 as it is on Android 12. So, when I modified one of my sample apps to use `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument` and `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri()`, I got `androidx.documentfile.provider.SingleDocumentFile@1e3ff95` from `toString()` on Android 11.

But, if you like, update your question with a complete sample showing how you are getting the `Uri`, how you are getting the `DocumentFile`, and how you are getting its text content via `toString()`, and we can try it out on our devices.

> What is the most concise way to get its content as String?

`TreeDocumentFile` is for a document tree, not a document. It has no content.

For a `DocumentFile` pointing to a document, call [`getUri()` on the `DocumentFile`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile#getUri()), pass that to `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`, and read in the `InputStream`.

Comment: I assure you that If I call it on previous versions `.toString()` on my `DocumentFile` object obtained with `findFile()` I get the content String, It isn't a my fantasy, If i call it in Android 12 I get that `androidx.documentfile.provider.TreeDocumentFile@81660cb` so certainly something is changed

Comment: @AndreaF, Interesting. Please show your code.

Comment: @AndreaF: You can look at the source code to `DocumentFile` and its related classes, and you will not find any code in there that matches your description. And, it does not change the fact that a document tree does not have content to print. You did not provide a [mcve]. But, as I suggested, you could create a sample project that proves your claims -- I for one would be very happy to look at it.